# Android On Startup App Sometimes Cannot Connect to WIFI Do I need delay

Tags: android

On powerup my app sometimes gets invalid server http response because I think wifi is not yet established.  Is there anyway to wait for wifi enablement before proceeding or what is best way to introduce delay until wifi is enabled.  Thanks

Comment: Why cant you use network data? You can setup a listener for when WiFi comes on, or you can scan for the availibilty of WiFi, using a backoff repetition and when its available fire off your http request.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this correct way to do it. You can use the below code to check for network connectivity and make a request.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;       
 }
```

Comment: thats part of it.  The problem is that it is perhaps not yet connected so how to do the delay until it changes.

Answer (score 0):

We met the same problem before and your guess is correct. In this case, a BroadcastReceiver should be registered (against android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED intent), when wifi gets connected, the receiver will be notified (in onReceive() callback method).

For more details, see official document on [WifiManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).